# What's the difference between swift and swiftc?

Tags: swift, macos

What's the difference between swift and swiftc?

I've read some resources saying that swiftc is a symbolic link to swift, but this is not the case on macOS Mojave 10.14.6:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  18288 Jul 29 23:49 /usr/bin/swiftc
```

Both swift and swiftc contains `OVERVIEW: Swift compiler` as part of their `--help` menu, but while their options are similar, they are different.

Answer (score 17):

`swift` is an interactive environment (REPL) for Swift.

`swiftc` is the Swift compiler.

The files in `/usr/bin` are just redirectors to the currently selected version (based on `xcode-select`). If you look at the filesize you'll note these are only 18kB. They're not the real executables.

The actual version can be found using xcrun:

```
$ xcrun -f swift
/Applications/Xcode-beta7.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift
```

If you look in that directory, you'll see that `swiftc` is a symlink to `swift` (which is a 90MB executable). The executable just checks what name it was run as, and adjusts its behavior accordingly.

Comment: `swift` can also run a swift program, and invoke the Swift package manager.

Comment: @RobNapier, thank you. How can swiftc be a symlink to swift? That's wierd; a compiler should not delegate it's functionality to a REPL. I also find it wierd, why `/use/bin/swift` is not implemented as a symlink to the currently selected `xcrun` version?

Comment: The compiler isn't delegating anything to a REPL. They're just the same binary. This is very common in the unix world.

Comment: With every command line invocation, you pass some items as an array. What's interesting is that the first item in that array is the name of the command itself. so if you run `swiftc foo.swift` that array of arguments would be `[swifc, foo.swift]` and just as Rob said, it's a symlink to the `swift` binary. So based on the first param, it will process it differently